# Click an item on listview and have a hidden/new item appear

Tags: java, android, listview

What I'm trying to do is hide the next item on listview, when we click previous items, the next hidden item will appear:

Example: Click A (item on listview), Apple (hidden next item on listview) will appear along with the sound. (ex: Apple)

[[image: Listview image]]

My code on activity :

```
public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
ListView GrelistView;
String[] greetings = {"A",
        "Apple",
        "B",
        "Ball"

};


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);
    GrelistView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.GrelistView);
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, greetings);
    GrelistView.setAdapter(adapter);
    GrelistView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), parent.getItemAtPosition(position) + "is selected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


        }

    });
}
```

Comment: might be you want to execute... expandable list view....?

Comment: use getItemposition to set the visibility of the next item to visible

Comment: Something like that. Let say we have A, apple(hidden), B, ball(hidden) on the listview, when we click A, apple will appear.

Answer (score 0):

I think @Chirag.T is right, what you are looking for is ExpendableListView , in which a down arrow for the subcategories will appear , when you click on that down arrow, your sub categories will show up.
Refer this below link -
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html

Comment: u can refer to my question again, i already posted along my code on activity.